# how to retrieve all the styles of a node in tiny mce?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I want to retrieve the styles of a node inside the tiny mce instance. With getStyle, I can get only the styles, that I will provide as an argument. But, I don't know which styles will be applied to the node by user. I mean user can apply NUMBER of styles such as font, font color, borders. I simply need to get the whole string inside the style attribute of the node. I tried with the getOuterHTML, but it stripes out the styles.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want easily using jQuery:

```
$(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getBody().firstChild).attr('style');
```